# Technologies for chat based on PHP server side

Tags: php, ajax, chat

I'm searching best technology for web-based chat and PHP server side. I don't know how much visits will have chat. But I think it's 50 users and more in one time.

I have read about long polling, short polling, websockets. But maybe there are more?
What advantages have websockets over polling?
Are there any libraries for crossbrowser websockets?

Comment: Too vague... perhaps you want to give more information of what you are aim for...

Comment: I fancy doing a bit of gardening. Which plants should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML5 WebSockets, Node.js, Comet. All good technologies to use, depends on your specific requirements.